# Talend - "Die on error" on component vs tRunjob

Tags: error-handling, talend

I have a talend main job (Single tRunjob) with error handling, the main job calls a subjob which has three "tRunjob" each has to execute sequentially one after the other on "On subjob ok" trigger. In order to test the main job error handling, I gave a wrong source file name to the "tDelimitedinputfile" component on the second tRunjob. When i executed the main job, instead of failing the Main job completed successfully, "Die on error" is enabled on all tRunjob in the sub and in the main job. Only after I enabled the "Die on error" in the "tDelimitedinputfile" component of the second job the main job is failing. so the question is
 Do we have to manually enable "Die on error" on each component inspite "Die on error" being enabled on the tRunjob?

Comment: yes its correct, as if you do not enable this die on error on the individual component, it does not throws the exception to main job in case of an error.

Comment: Are there any problems in enabling "Die on error" for all components at project level and  is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The components have to throw the error forward to the job, which in turn will only throw the error forward if itself has the option enabled.

There are no downsides to this. Reason for this is that some jobs or components don't need any error handling.

Comment: Thanks again tobi, Is there anyway to set "Die on error" as the default setting at the project level for all components?

Comment: No problem. I don't know about any of those options, but maybe there are available somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to set DieOnError for all Components. In the case of TInputFileDelimited, it is not considered an error if there is a missing file, unless you check the box. Seems odd; but that's the way it is with this component.

Always look for the checkbox on components so that you'll know how they behave.